# Angular JS $http service config object properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider the following example:

```
$http.post(url, data, config)
```

It is clear about `url` and  `data` parameters. What about `config` I wasn't able to find in internet what set of properties the `config` object can have. I know of one: `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}`, but there can be others as well. Is there a document that describes the `config` objec/param property list in details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That parameter is well documented on this page:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage

Apart from the `headers` property, you can set the `timeout`, `cache`, `responseType` among others